# Only make button clickable when something is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a button that can only be pressed when all the options from 1 box are moved to the other box.

see screenshot of the interface are here:

[interface](https://gyazo.com/140b21563a91e7d44516958a4a8bd0f1)

so all the options from the blue box are dragged in the green box and then the button becomes active. is this possible?

my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
      $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
     }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable, .connectedSortable1"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id='div2' class='dropboxes'>
   <!--box with options to drag to the other box-->
   <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='I'>option1</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='D'>option2</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='C'>option3</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='S'>option4</li>
   </ul>

   <!--other box where the options above can be dropped-->
   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable1">
   </ul>
   
   <!--this button has to be only clickable when all the options are dragged to the other box-->
   <button class="next">Volgende</button>
 </div>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: you want to move your options from 1st listbox to 2nd listbox, Right ?

Comment: that is already working. i want the button only to work when all the options are moved from 1st box to 2nd box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using .drop event of sortable. Please check snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
    .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
      $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable, .connectedSortable1",
      stop: function( ) {
        if($("#sortable1 li").length > 0){
          $(".next").prop("disabled",true);
        }else{
          $(".next").prop("disabled",false);
        }
      }
    }).disableSelection();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id='div2' class='dropboxes'>
   <!--box with options to drag to the other box-->
   <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='I'>option1</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='D'>option2</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='C'>option3</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default" style="cursor:move;" id='S'>option4</li>
   </ul>

   <!--other box where the options above can be dropped-->
   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable1">
     Drag Here
   </ul>
   
   <!--this button has to be only clickable when all the options are dragged to the other box-->
   <button disabled="disabled" class="next">Volgende</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons can be disabled and enabled with their HTML `disabled` attribute

```
<button id="nextBtn" disabled="true">Disabled</button>
```

With access to DOM events and the moveable items you can check when objects are dragged over. When all have been moved then change the button's disabled attribute.

```
document.getElementById('nextBtn').disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's is one of the possible way

If you have predefined number of options you could use counter provided you should make sure  that the same option doesn't get clicked twice ,and then in the button click function check the counter value.

eg. 5 options counter  value should be 5

if counter == 5

perform button click

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using the `contentChanged` event listener. Since you are using jQuery already, this might help.

```
$('#sortable2').on('contentChanged', function(){
    if($(this).children().length == 4)
        $('.next').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

This code is checking if the contents on the right hand list has changed and if so, we are checking if the number of list items present are 4 and enabling the button by setting it's attribute `disabled` to `false`. If you don't know the number of items on the left hand side, pre calculate and pass it to the call back while checking items on the right side.